# How does Alexa handle special characters in synonymns for Custom Slot Type Values?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Consider the following Custom Slot Type Value synonymns:

```
"name": {
  "value": "The Thing",
  "synonyms": [
    "Foo & Bar",
    "foo 2",
    "foo 10.5",
    "foo/bar"
  ]
}
```

How will Alexa handle these synonyms with special characters? The documentation only gives examples of using lowercase latin characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of a custom slot type can contain alphabetic characters only. The only special character allowed is the underscore (“_”). The dot character (.) is allowed, but only when extending one of the built-in types that allows custom values. That is, you can define a custom slot type called AMAZON.US_CITY if you want to add additional cities to the list, but you cannot define a custom slot type called AMAZON.DATE or MYDEV.MY_CUSTOM_SLOT

Source :- https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#custom-slot-syntax

Comment: I glossed over that help article because I it didn't specifically reference 'synonyms', but it would make sense that the same rules apply. However, in my experience, I have found that numerical digits do seem to work.